# XmlValueDisconnectedException even after initiating a new instance

Tags: java, apache-poi

I know there is a bug , so I read many work around methods and it appears that the most popular is to start a `new` instance of `FileInputStream`

So I tried

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++) {

FileInputStream out = new FileInputStream ( new File ( "  C:\\  .xlsx ") ) ;  // new 

....

out close(); //make sure to get rid of it

}
```

However, this still throws this exception

---

There is a patch for on [this page](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49940)

```
if (prev != null) {
   /*CTRow ctRow = prev.getCTRow();
   / ctRow.set(CTRow.Factory.newInstance()); */ <--- to be removed
   Iterator it = prev.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()) {
      it.next();
      it.remove();
   }

}
```

But i am not sure how to use it

Comment: If you think you're affected by that bug, then why not upgrade to a newer version of Apache POI that includes the fix to it?

Comment: Purpose of assigning and closing FileInputStream inside a loop is not clear to me. I mean why you want to do this? If your purpose is to reload the same file multiple times after performing write operation, then you should better use http://stackoverflow.com/a/18262235/624003