# org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException when creating ConditionalFormattingRule

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create a `XSSFConditionalFormattingRule` with a 3-scale coloring. Therefore I need to set the thresholds as well. Yet upon debugging I found that each `XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold` throws an `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.` on their `CTCfvo` property, but only after calling `rule.getColorScaleFormatting().setNumControlPoints(3);`

My complete code is this:

```
CellRangeAddress[] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf("Z2:Z" + (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1)) };

XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting()
        .createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule();

XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold thresh5 = rule.getColorScaleFormatting().createThreshold();
thresh5.setRangeType(RangeType.NUMBER);
thresh5.setValue(0.05);
XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold thresh10 = rule.getColorScaleFormatting().createThreshold();
thresh10.setRangeType(RangeType.NUMBER);
thresh10.setValue(0.10);
XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold thresh15 = rule.getColorScaleFormatting().createThreshold();
thresh15.setRangeType(RangeType.NUMBER);
thresh15.setValue(0.15);

rule.getColorScaleFormatting().setNumControlPoints(3);
rule.getColorScaleFormatting()
        .setThresholds(new ConditionalFormattingThreshold[] { thresh5, thresh10, thresh15 });
XSSFColor colorGreen = new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.GREEN, colorMap);
XSSFColor colorYellow = new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW, colorMap);
XSSFColor colorRed = new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.RED, colorMap);

rule.getColorScaleFormatting().setColors(new Color[] { colorGreen, colorYellow, colorRed });

sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting().addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule);
```

And this the *shortened stacktrace* I get when execting the code above:

> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1258)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.newCursor(XmlObjectBase.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl.arraySetterHelper(XmlComplexContentImpl.java:1124)
>     at
>   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColorScaleImpl.setCfvoArray(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColorScaleFormatting.setThresholds(XSSFColorScaleFormatting.java:85)

**What causes the error I am seeing here? Is it a mistake when I create the `XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold`? Or something entirely else?**

---

I am using apache poi v4.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the question, the only occurences of this error was attributed to writing the workbook twice ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261152/org-apache-xmlbeans-impl-values-xmlvaluedisconnectedexception-when-write-workboo), [bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49940)). So that got me wondering what I am doing wrong. I had no real idea where to start, as everything associated with the error has nothing to do with my problem.

My first look went to the documentation of `void org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColorScaleFormatting.setNumControlPoints(int num)`, which states the following:

> Sets the number of control points to use to map the colours. Should
>   normally be 2 or 3.
>
> After updating, you need to ensure that the Threshold count and Color
>   count match

The second part caught my eye. I thought something along the lines:

> I create the thresholds directly on the `ColorScaleFormatting` with `getColorScaleFormatting().createThreshold()`. So what if `setNumControlPoints()` actually resets all the thresholds which have been previously created?

And that was the point where I simply moved `rule.getColorScaleFormatting().setNumControlPoints(3);` in before the creation of all the `XSSFConditionalFormattingThreshold` and there it was, my code working just fine.

Having a look at the `setNumControlPoints` method we can see this:

```
public void setNumControlPoints(int num) {
    while (num < _scale.sizeOfCfvoArray()) {
        _scale.removeCfvo(_scale.sizeOfCfvoArray()-1);
        _scale.removeColor(_scale.sizeOfColorArray()-1);
    }
    while (num > _scale.sizeOfCfvoArray()) {
        _scale.addNewCfvo();
        _scale.addNewColor();
    }
}
```

This clearly suggests that some things might get removed when calling this method, though I couldn't quite get what the initial size of `_scale.sizeOfCfvoArray()` is (I'd assume 0). And because of that I couldn't quite see how stuff gets removed, because I created 3 thresholds (`_scale.sizeOfCfvoArray()` should be 3) and then I call `setNumControlPoints(3)`, so we would have `num == _scale.sizeOfCfvoArray()` and I couldn't find anything for what happens in that case (looks like complete removal of everything though).

To conclude, `setNumControlPoints(int num)` should always be called as first thing after creating the rule and before creating any thresholds.

---

<sub>If anyone can point out why everything gets reset if `num == _scale.sizeOfCfvoArray()`, feel free to comment or edit.</sub>